# Poor performance in writing a cython library

Tags: cython

**test.pyx** is:

```
import gzip, re
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cpdef np.ndarray[np.uint32_t, ndim=2] collect_qualities(str file_in, int length):
    '''
    What it Does:
    ------------
    bla bla bla

    Input:
    -----
    file_in: path-filename
    length: length of each sequence

    Output:
    ------
    numpy array with shape (n,m) where n=length of reads and m=solexa scores
    '''
 
    cdef str solexa_scores = '!"#$%&' + "'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHI"

    cdef np.ndarray[np.uint32_t, ndim=1] N = np.zeros(shape=length, dtype=np.uint32) # This is the divisor of the mean
    cdef np.ndarray[np.uint32_t, ndim=2] sums = np.zeros(shape=(length, len(solexa_scores)+33), dtype=np.uint32) # This is the dividend of the mean
    
    cdef counter=0 # Useful to know if it's the 3rd or 4th line of the current sequence in fastq.
    with gzip.open(file_in, "rb") as f:
        for line in f:
        
            if counter%4==0: # first line of the sequence (obtain tail info)
                tile = line.decode('utf-8').split(':')[4]
                counter=0
        
            elif counter%3==0: # 3rd line of the sequence (obtain the qualities)
                for n, score in enumerate(line.decode('utf-8')):
                    sums[n, ord(score)] +=1
                    
            counter+=1
    return sums
```

**setup.py** is:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

setup(
        ext_modules = cythonize("test.pyx"),
        include_dirs=[numpy.get_include()]
)
```

It compiles with a warning about a deprecated numpy API.

**python.py** is:

```
import gzip, re
import numpy as np

def collect_qualities(file_in, length):
    '''
    What it Does:
    ------------
    bla bla bla

    Input:
    -----
    file_in: path-filename
    length: length of each sequence

    Output:
    ------
    numpy array with shape (n,m) where n=length of reads and m=solexa scores
    '''
 
    solexa_scores = '!"#$%&' + "'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHI"
    
    N = np.zeros(shape=length, dtype=np.uint32) # This is the divisor of the mean
    sums = np.zeros(shape=(length, len(solexa_scores)+33)) # This is the dividend of the mean
    
    counter=0 # Useful to know if it's the 3rd or 4th line of the current sequence in fastq.
    with gzip.open(file_in, "rb") as f:
        for line in f:
        
            if counter%4==0: # first line of the sequence (obtain tail info)
                tile = line.decode('utf-8').split(':')[4]
                counter=0
        
            elif counter%3==0: # 3rd line of the sequence (obtain the qualities)
                for n, score in enumerate(line.decode('utf-8')):
                    sums[n, ord(score)] +=1
                    
            counter+=1
    return sums
```

Then I import the functions in ipython and compare their running times.

For a fairly small input files, python takes ~140 seconds while the cython-compiled ~950 seconds.

**What am I doing wrong in cython?**

Thank you!

Comment: There's a lot of stuff unoptimized here (and equally a lot of the stuff you have "optimized" is unlikely to affect performance, for example using a `cpdef` function is probably pretty pointless). And you don't use `solexa_scores` or `N`, which looks like a mistake. But it's a bit puzzling that it'd go _slower_. I'd expect it to be roughly the same. `cython -a` should give you an annotated html file with some indications of what might be slow.

Comment: I think this'd need so example data for people to be able to help you. I don't really believe your timings here for example, but I have no way to investigate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comments: I don't really believe your timings and think there's probably something else going on here (for example that you're inadvertently using an old version you have installed somewhere that does something different). I'd expect Cython to be marginally faster here, but not significantly. It's also impossible for me to actually test any of my suggestions with the information provided.

However, some suggestions:

First, a number of things you done are pointless, or tiny pessimizations.

1. There's no point in using a `cpdef` function since the internals of `def` and `cpdef`/`cdef` functions are compiled identically. Using `c[p]def` gives you slightly quicker function calls from C/Cython which is valuable for small functions that are called a lot. I doubt this applies here.
2. Specifying the return type is probably pointless.
3. Typing `file_in` is marginally worse than leaving it untyped - Cython can't useful optimize it since it only passes it to the `open` function so probably just loses time doing a type-check.

There's then a few missed opportunities for optimization:

1. `counter` should be typed as an `int` (`cdef counter` just makes it a generic Python object).
2. It might be worth typing `line` as a `str` (you'll need to do this at the top of the function rather than when `line` is used in the for-loop).
3. It's probably worth having an intermediate `decoded_line` typed as `bytes`  (e.g. `decoded_line = line.decode(...)`) since this is what is being iterated over. It's possible that Cython can deduce this on it's own from `str.decode` but it's better to be sure.
4. It's usually better in Cython to do direct iteration over a range rather than use things like `enumerate`. (This is different to Python). Do `for n in range(len(decoded_line)): score = decoded_line[n]`. It's possible that Cython can make this optimization itself, but do it yourself to be sure.
5. It might be worth turning of boundchecking and wraparound using [compiler directives](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html#compiler-directives). My advice is to do this as locally as possible (i.e. don't just wrap every function with them in a cargo-cult manner, but think about where it helps and whether it's safe).
6. `sums` has a different `dtype` in your Python and Cython version (`uint32` in Cython, `double` in Python). Think about which is right.
7. Use `cython -a` to get an annotated html version of your function that highlights unoptimized bits. Worry about important loops that are highlighted - don't get too hung up of stuff that's only called once.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I first tried `int count` but I got an error that is not defined by the compiler or cython. However, when I try `cdef int counter`, test.pyx is transtaled to test.c and compiled to the _file.so_.  Do you have a fast guess of why?

Comment: BTW, after including ALL your suggestions, it went from ~950 seconds to 13 seconds!! Thanks a LOT!! 
Please, let me know if you are intrigued of any additional informatoin that I have missed here and could be helpful.

Comment: I don't know why test.pyx -> test.c -> file.so. That's very odd and I'd actually expect it to break (the filename has to match the name of the initialization function that Cython generates). Glad it helped.